# Fourier transform of a "Gaussian" function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

For $A$ a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with nonzero determinant and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, let $f(x)=e^{-i(Ax\cdot x)/2}$ be a complex-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^n$; notice it is a tempered distribution since $|f|=1$ everywhere. What is its Fourier transform (in a distributional sense, because $f\not\in L^1$)?

I can do some progress as follows: assume $n=1, A=1$. Then $f=e^{-ix^2/2}$ so $f'=-ixf$. Moreover we know that the Fourier transform "exchanges multiplication and differentiation". So taking the Fourier transform of the previous equation, we get $ix(\hat{f}) = \widehat{f'}=\widehat{-ixf} = (\hat{f})'$. Setting $g=\hat{f}$ we get $g' = ixg$. This forces $g(x)=Ce^{ix^2/2}$, and we can compute $C$ plugging in some "easy function", like $\psi=e^{-x^2}$. But I'm not sure about the rigourosity of this argument.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your approach in the $n=1,\ A=1$ case is fine. I've primarily seen it be used for $e^{-\alpha x^2},$ with $\alpha>0,$ but it should also work in this case.

Comment: In the multidimensional case, diagonalize the matrix: $A = SDS^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just like to close this question by posting my solution, which I'm quite sure gives the right answer despite the slightly non-rigorous step involving solving the differential equation for $\hat{f}$. This might be well-known theory, but I'm unaware of it.

[image]

[image]